# Как с делать ветки в D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

Я использовал пример http://bl.ocks.org/jdarling/2d4e84460d5f5df9c0ff и мне надо сделать ветки похожие на пример из картинки[image: пример веток]

помогите мне если сможете, спасибо за внимание

Comment: Как насчет того чтобы взять тот пример из D3.js и у себя использовать?

Comment: мне нужно сделать такие же ветки как на картинке, сужающие ветки

Comment: не поверишь я его и использую